# Click events not firing for multiple Google Tag Manager / Analytics implementation

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have two Google Tag Manager installations on the same website. Each of these GTM accounts have tags set up to include a Google Analytics account (universal, and these are separate accounts). So, there are 2 GTM and 2 GA accounts. Then, in both GTM accounts, there is a tag set up to handle a click event - both tags in both accounts are handling a click event for the same element. The trigger for these tags is on a click when an element contains a certain class (this is through the GTM Click Classes).

I never see the click event in both GA accounts at the same time. Sometimes, I see the event in one of the GA accounts, other times I see the event in the other GA account. But, the same unique occurrence of an event only ever shows in one of the GA accounts. Why is this the case and is there any way to get the events to show up in both GA accounts at the same time?

Here is the debug output from the Chrome extension Tag Assistant:

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
    Running command: ga("create", "UA-Axxxxxx-1", {name: "gtm1432654637584"})
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637584.set", "&gtm", "GTM-Cxxxxx")
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637584.set", "hitCallback", [function])
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637584.send", "pageview")
    Running command: ga("create", "UA-Byyyyyy-1", {name: "gtm1432654637594"})
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637594.set", "&gtm", "GTM-Dyyyyy")
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637594.set", "hitCallback", [function])
    Running command: ga("gtm1432654637594.send", "pageview")
Initializing Google Analytics.
    Tracking script already loaded. Abandoning initialization.
```

Both GTM and GA accounts are working correctly, as far as I can tell, other than this event tracking issue (page views come through, Tag Assistant shows the installation is correct, etc). Also, the `dataLayer` variables are renamed to something unique for both GTM implementations.

Comment: Have you tried to just use one container and double tag (one tag with one GA ID, and the other tag with the other GA ID), and see if both tags are fired for the one event?

Comment: @nyuen No, but I'll try that and report back.